# How to make reverse nested serialization when we have ManytoMany field in relation? using DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

my data model is like

```py
class Rack(models.Model):

    rack_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=30, verbose_name="Rack Id")
    rack_set        = models.ForeignKey(RackSet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='wh_rack_set', verbose_name="Rack Set")

    class Meta:
        db_table =  "rw_rack"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rack_name

class RackBay(models.Model):

    bay_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=30, verbose_name="Bay Id")
    rack            = models.ForeignKey(Rack, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='wh_rack', verbose_name="Rack")
    class Meta:
        db_table = "rw_bay"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bay_name

class RackShelf(models.Model):

    shelf_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=50, verbose_name="Shelf Id")
    bay           = models.ForeignKey(RackBay, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='wh_rack_bay', verbose_name="Bay")

    class Meta:
        db_table ="rw_shelf"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.shelf_name

class RackBin(models.Model):

    bin_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=50, verbose_name="Bin Id")
 
    class Meta:
        db_table = "rw_bin"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bin_name

class CargoWarehouseSurvey(models.Model):
          
    job_id      = models.ForeignKey(WarehouseJob, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='inputted_job_order', verbose_name="Job Id")
    warehouse_locations      = models.ManyToManyField(WarehouseCell, help_text='Assigned warehouse locations for current survey job.', related_name='warehouse_locations_set')
    rack_bin_locations       = models.ManyToManyField(RackBin, help_text='Assigned rack_bin locations for current survey job.', related_name='rack_bin_locations_set')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'warehouses_survey'
        ordering = ['id']
```

This is my data model, in CargoWarehouseSurvey has bins relation what ever the selected, i need to get bin belogs to which rack, bay, shelf, bin. like

expected Response is

```
"allotted_bins": [
    {
      "rack_id": "A-1",
      "bays": [
        {
          "bay_id": "B-1",
          "shelves": [
            {
              "shelf_id": "S1",
              "bin_ids": [
                "12343",
        "21232"
              ]
            }, 
       {
              "shelf_id": "S2",
              "bin_ids": [
                "43234",
        "42354"
              ]
            },

          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you update the question with your serializers as well?

Comment: i have done the solution